# Get only the header from icecast live stream

Tags: bash, unix, curl, wget, icecast

I would like to get **only** the header information for a live icecast stream in `bash`. I would like to use the information

```
Content-Type: audio/ogg
```

to take certain actions.

I have tried `curl` and `wget` however it seams the icecast server does not accept the HEAD command so I cannot use `curl --head` or `-I`.

What I have got to work is is

```
curl -s -m 1 -D - -o /dev/null http://stream.radioreklama.bg:80/radio1_low.ogg | grep Content-Type
```

***just using an example stream from the icecast directory (http://dir.xiph.org/)

The issue with this is the `-m 1` i.e. it still fetches 1 second of content. I do not want any content, just grab the headers and end.

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: Your `grep` command should work fine, what is the issue you are facing? Show us the exact output you need.

Comment: `php -r "print_r(get_headers('http://stream.radioreklama.bg:80/radio1_low.ogg'));"`

Comment: The question is around removing the need to fetch content. How can it be done with the -m option? I.woild like to get rid of the 1 second delay imposed by this command.

Comment: @QuickPrototype: You already have only 1 second delay, why do you want to remove it altogether?

Comment: @QuickPrototype: Check my update, just do `curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{content_type}' 'google.com'`

Comment: @Inian doing that for google.com is fine because the page is small. You cannot do that for a live stream as the content is endless.